# Table thead element adds padding on top of the page in Chrome browser in Print Preview

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table, padding

I have a simple peace of html code which doesn't display as I want in Chrome browser.
**The problem**: when I print preview this page in Chrome, I see a small padding, from which I cannot get rid of. The printer's margins are set to NONE. It displays fine in Firefox though.

If I replace <thead> with <tbody> the padding disappears. I can not use tbody because my layout requires repeating the header on each printed page.

 I'm using Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) on MS Windows 7 64bit Professional.
Any ideas about this behaviour?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>test</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It seems like a Chrome bug, but I can't find an opened issue in bugs.chromium.org

Comment: Thanks for checking, shaochuancs. I've just reported the issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721735